# Can I easily track site performance over time with Google PageSpeed?

Tags: google, analytics, performance, page-speed

Are there any implementations of the Google PageSpeed API that allow one to track the performance of a site over time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - Google Analytics has this built-in. Go to Behaviour > Site Speed > Overview to see the average site speed over time. Or check Page Timings for the speed of individual pages.

Comment: Keep in mind that page timings provided by google are highly unreliable and often (if not always) will show you different results than custom-written scripts or other 3rd party tools. It's more to see trends in changes (eg. "_server slowed down by 50% during a year period_") than measure an actual performance.

Comment: @Marcin Google's page timings are all from real world visitors to the site being tracked, so for the most part they cannot be "unreliable". However, they do occasionally suffer from big outliers - see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20165/is-it-normal-to-have-some-huge-anomolies-in-google-analytics-site-speed-tracking